# \leftmark header: decreasing the distance between the chapter name and the chapter-number

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

After compiling the following document, it seems that there are at least two white-spaces between `chapter 1` and `blablabla`  in the header of page 3.

How I can control this distance? Increasing or decreasing it? Or reducing it to a single white-space?

```
   \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \begin{document}

    \chapter{blablabla}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\ \ Title}
    \fancyhead[OR]{\leftmark\ \ \thepage}

    \newpage 
    a
    \newpage 
    b
    \end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar My first thought as well, but not the issue :-) There really are two spaces defined in `book.cls` (`\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %`).

Comment: @HarishKumar no, this decreases the distance between the chapter-name and the page-number. My question is to decrease the distance between the chapter-number and the chapter-name (i.e. the distance between `Chapter 1.` and `blablabla`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is a double space as can be seen when looking at a snippet from `book.cls`

```
\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
```

Witch introduces two spaces after the period. One way to get rid of that extra space, is patching the command `\chaptermark`, which is executed to update the header information when a chapter starts.

To add a little more to the answer than this short little hack, i used the alternative package `scrlayer-scrpage` to set the header and footer. It is very powerful.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{. \ }{.\ }{}{}% <- magic here
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rohead{\leftmark\ \ \pagemark}
\lehead{\pagemark\ \ Title}
\begin{document}

\chapter{blablabla}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{} 
%\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\ \ Title}
%\fancyhead[OR]{\leftmark\ \
%\thepage}


\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I would be grateful if it would be possible to provide an answer with my original setting with `fancyhdr`. The reason is that in my original document I heavily used fancyhdr, and it is too complicated to change it.

Comment: @Name The issue is unrelated to any package. It was just an alternative, you can use fancyhdr as before. ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks, one should insert the magic after `\fancyhf{}`.